# App crashes when popover appears

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uipopovercontroller, popover

I am trying to get a popover appear on a press of a button in ios 8, however the app crashes on the press of the button. I have set up all storyboards correctly and using breakpoints I determined that it is this line that causes the problem even though the view controller which is meant to be displayed in the popover is of FirstViewController class:

```
UIViewController *vc = destNav.viewControllers.firstObject;
```

This is the crash:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SecondViewController viewControllers]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1446ea3a0'

---

This is the rest of my code from this part:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
// Assuming you've hooked this all up in a Storyboard with a popover presentation style
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"popover"]) {
    UINavigationController *destNav = segue.destinationViewController;
    FirstViewController *vc = destNav.viewControllers.firstObject;

    // This is the important part
    UIPopoverPresentationController *popPC = destNav.popoverPresentationController;
    popPC.delegate = self;
}
}

- (UIModalPresentationStyle)adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller {
return UIModalPresentationNone;
}
```

Comment: Most likely `destNav.viewControllers.firstObject` is `nil`. Can you post the error message in your question as well?

Comment: Post details about the crash. Which line exactly is it crashing on? What is the complete and exact error message of the crash?

Comment: I have added the error message to the question and the exact line was in the question initially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out! Sorry that I am posting this quite late

You simply need to exclude the line

```
 FirstViewController *vc = destNav.viewControllers.firstObject;
```

even though all tutorials show this line

Answer (score -1):

try casting your view controller like this:

```
FirstViewController *vc = (FirstViewController *)destNav.viewControllers.firstObject;
```

Comment: 1) Pointer casts are only for compile time and would have no effect at runtime. 2) This cast is unnecessary because `firstObject` returns an `id` which can be assigned, without cast, to any pointer type.